# How to create scroll effect like facebook ads page?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to create a scroll effect like the one in this link:

https://www.facebook.com/ads/about/?campaign_id=366925476690229&placement=egot&extra_1=not-admgr-user

if any one knows a tool making this or how to make it by jquery i will be grateful.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one.

Similar but not exactly

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html